# What happens to the addEventListener when I remove node?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, dom-events, addeventlistener, onclicklistener

I generate objects dynamically, and when they are created, I add click event listener to them:

```
let elements = document.getElementsByClassName("my-class")

for (let element of elements) {
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
        // here I do my job
    }, false)
}
```

After that, some objects may be deleted by the user. I take them off with this method:

```
element.remove()
```

And now I want to understand what happens next:

- Does this listener still exist? I hope that listeners became 1 less. But how to check it?
- Do I really need to worry about the large number of listeners? how large a number of listeners can become a problem? I'm afraid my app will break.

Comment: The element is removed, so is the event listener.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do I need to remove event listeners before removing elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033821/do-i-need-to-remove-event-listeners-before-removing-elements)

Comment: When you remove an element with element.remove(), the event listener that was added to it using element.addEventListener() is automatically removed as well. So you don't have to worry about it still existing and causing any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this question’s answer

[If a DOM Element is removed, are its listeners also removed from memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12528049/if-a-dom-element-is-removed-are-its-listeners-also-removed-from-memory)

Event Listener will be collected by garbage collector algorithm with the removed node if no reference to it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the listener still exists. In Chrome and FF devtools, there is a function called `getEventListener(node)`. Experiment with it, and notice that even after your call `el.remove()`, there are still event listeners attached to that element.
[image: browser console]

This means that if we remove an element and add the same element to anywhere in our HTML, the event listener still works:

```js
const c = document.getElementById("c")

c.addEventListener("click", () => alert("clicked"))

setTimeout(() => c.remove(), 1000)
setTimeout(() => document.body.appendChild(c), 2000)
```

```html
<button id="c">click</button>
```

But is this necessarily a problem? No, not really. The browser optimizes your code and, as mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631265/addeventlistener-memory-leaks), that isn't something that should bother you. Your concern for overloading events, as well, should not be an issue; browsers have been optimized for decades; your events are stored in a list of listeners for a specific event that is only looked up when the user fires the event.

The only way I envision a problem is if you leave everything dangling and don't clean it up with scope. Take this example:

```js
const length = 1_000_000
const elements = Array.from({ length }, () => {
  const el = document.createElement("button")
  el.addEventListener("click", () => alert("do something..."))
})

elements.forEach(el => el.remove()) // <-- this does NOT free up our listener functions, however
```

As mentioned, we can use scope to automatically discard our values or explicitly call `el.removeEventListener` (but you'll need a reference to that function).

Answer (score -1):

- No, If you remove element from DOM then its associated
  event listeners is also removed as well.
- If you want to remove event listener without removing element use

```
element.removeEventListener(type,()=>{ 
    console.log("Event Removed")
)}
```

Comment: This would not remove any event listener. The method takes the reference of the function to be removed, thus supplying a new function gives it a new reference and not one that was already attached. See [removeEventListener on anonymous functions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4950115) and [How can I remove a JavaScript event listener?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4402287)